# using this keyword with javascript prototype addEventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I want to use this keyword in event listener function.

```
var MyViewModel = function (file) {
    this.status = "";

    this.xm = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    this.xm.addEventListener("load", this.onLoad, false);
};

MyViewModel.prototype.onLoad = function (e) {
    this.status = "ok";
};
```

I can not access the **MyViewModel** object with **this** keyword in onLoad prototype.

- **this** object is **window**.
- **e** parameter is XmlHttpRequest

How can I access this?

Comment: `this` should be the `xm` object?

Comment: You can't access object inside static methods. Make `onLoad` a private method instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem with **jQuery.proxy**

This is specifying function scope.

```
var MyViewModel = function (file) {
    this.status = "";

    this.xm = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    this.xm.addEventListener("load",  $.proxy(this.onLoad, this), false);
};

MyViewModel.prototype.onLoad = function (e) {
    this.status = "ok";
};
```

Now you can use this keyword as MyViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery you could also do something like:

```
function MyViewModel(file) {
    this.status = "";
    this.xm = new XMLHttpRequest();   
    var viewModel = this;
    this.xm.addEventListener("load", function(){viewModel.onLoad()}, false);
}
```

so that a reference to the instance is held in a closure using *viewModel* and then used to set *this* to the required value in the call.